# Create thick Gyroid

Tags: matlab

I want to give thickness to a Gyroid Function for Gyroid is

```
Gyroid=(cos(x) .* sin(y) + cos(y) .* sin(z) + cos(z) .* sin(x));
% Reverse Gyroid
R=sqrt( (-sin(x).*sin(y)+cos(x).*cos(z)).^2+(-
sin(y).*sin(z)+cos(y).*cos(x)).^2+(-sin(z).*sin(x)+cos(z).*cos(y)).^2 );
ReverseGyroid=(Gyroid.*T./R);
isosurface(Gyroid)
isosurface(ReverseGyroid)
```

Currently I am getting two surfaces. I want to close the gaps using isocaps.
[current outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nAMs.png)

This is the output I expect but as one Isosurface def and not by using isosurface separately for both surfaces.
[desired outcome should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI9mE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar problem. I'm taking as a reference the gyroid formula from Wikipedia, I have a code that would create an .stl file for 3D printing.

The following code just calculates the gyroid for a single unit from -pi to +pi, it makes the offest with the value t where v-t=0 is one surface and v+t = 0 is the other surface, by multiplying both it gets 0 values when either the first or the second surface are 0, thus by doing isosurface evaluated at 0 you get either of them.
isocaps work for every value that is "below" 0 thus filling the surface on the boundary between both surfaces.

I did this on octave but I think this code shuld run on matlab.

```
[x, y, z] = meshgrid (-pi:pi/16:pi);
v = sin(x).*cos(y)+sin(y).*cos(z)+sin(z).*cos(x); %gyroid formula
t=0.15; % offset from isovalue, affects thickness
v=(v-t).*(v+t); %multiplies one negative offset gyroid and one positive offset gyroid
figure(1)
isosurface (x, y, z, v, 0);
hold on
figure(1)
isocaps(x,y,z,v,0,"below");
```

Comment: Ok, I added a brief explanation.